# What site would I ask about password length requirements?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, site-recommendation

I am interested in learning whether there is any technical reason so many websites restrict passwords to short lengths.

Would this be appropriate for Stack Overflow? It seems to be fairly off topic for there but I'm not sure if there is a better Stack Exchange site.

edit - for those interested, [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33470/what-technical-reasons-are-there-to-have-low-maximum-password-lengths) is the question.

Comment: I would say [security.SE]!

Comment: @HugoDozois indeed, that appears to be prefect!

Comment: And don't forget to check for duplicates before posting. eg. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6287/should-i-have-a-maximum-password-length

Comment: @SztupY I did, and found that question is not the same as the one I am asking (and have asked)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I would post it on [IT Security](http://security.stackexchange.com). By looking at their [FAQ](https://security.stackexchange.com/faq) it seems appropriate. Just make sure the question is well scoped and is not worded too generally. They don't like too open-ended question.

In case you didn't know, there's a [complete list of the sites here](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic)! And you can use the search bar at the top to find a site appropriate to the keywords you want!